# To update a program should I uninstall previous version

Tags: uninstall

As the title said, I would like to know which is better to update a program: should I  uninstall previous version first or keep it ?

Specifically I am planning to update my matlab.

Comment: You should follow the guidance of the program publisher - if the publisher says that you should uninstall old versions before installing new, then that's what you should do. Otherwise, it's probably OK to install and overwrite-in-place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not need to uninstall the software to update/upgrade it. You can install a newer version and upgrade, even if the installer itself does not support upgrading. Here are some reasons why you should not uninstall:

1. Updaters

   - Usually, most programs come with updaters built-in. Uninstalling the corresponding app would merely break the updater.
2. APT and other package managers (reinstalling)

   - If you're using Linux, many distros come with their own package manager. In this post, I will be using `apt` (found in distros such as Mint, Debian, Ubuntu, and Raspberry Pi OS) as an example.
   - If you installed a package using `apt`'s `install` option, you can update the package by using these commands:
   - First, run the `update` option with the `--fix-missing` parameter enabled. This will update the package repos. If it complains about the `Suite` value being changed (this happens often when you're running an `unstable`, `testing`, or `oldstable` release of Linux), say yes, and wait for the `$` prompt to appear again.
   - Then run the same command again, this time using the `upgrade` option.
   - And finally, use the `reinstall` option on the package(s) you want to update (again, using the `--fix-missing` parameter).
   - Note: You can put these commands into a shell script, type `chmod +x [filename here]` into the command prompt(1), run it, and then run the shell script anytime you want to update it.

TL;DR: Use the built-in updater, or use your Linux package manager.

Hope this helps,

Depths (0v0)

(1) - where "[filename here]" is the name of the script, this command is needed to make the script runnable.